# magento extension installation

Tags: php, magento, pear

I want to install a Magento extension in WAMP, but not from the Magento connect system.

How can I do this? I have the module (extension) code and I already installed the sample data in the Magento installation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You place the code in

```
app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename
```

Where `Packagename/Modulename` applied to your specific module (if you have the code it should already be in this structure)

Then, in

```
app/etc/modules
```

Add an XML file named `Packagename_Modulename.xml` with the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Packagename_Modulename>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Packagename_Modulename>>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Again, replacing `Packagename_Modulename` with the specific packagename and module name of the module you're installing.

You'll need to clear your Magento cache to see the changes take place.

Answer (score 0):

The above won't really help you if what you have is a packaged magento extension, as this will already contain the correct directory structure magento requires.

If you have downloaded a packaged extension you will usually have the directory structure packaged in a tar.gz / zip file such as this:

app/

skin/

If you have a directory structure like this you can just paste the files into your Magento root directory, Magento will find the module for you.

you should ALWAYS perform a backup before installing an extension :-)

Answer (score 0):

To install Magento 2 extension follow the instructions bellow:

1. Back up your web directory and store database.
2. Download installation package.
3. Upload content of the installation package to your store root folder via FTP/SFTP; install magento 2 extension.
4. Connect to your store root directory with SSH:

   ```
   cd path_to_the_store_root_folder
   ```

   Run 3 commands bellow:

   ```
   php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile menu_console
   ```
5. Flush store cache, log out from the backend and log in again

   Execute the following command

   ```
   php -f bin/magento cache:clean menu_clear_cache
   ```

   Or go to Back-end > System > Cache Management. Click the following buttons to completely clear the store cache:

   - Flush Mangento Cache
   - Flush Cache Storage
   - Flush Catalog Images Cache
   - Flush Javascripts/CSS cache